# Looking for a small analog pointing device, suitable for attaching to a tented split keyboard

Tags: bluetooth, mice, ergonomics, trackball

I just purchased a tented split keyboard to alleviate some of the repetitive stress on my hands from typing, which I use with my MacBook Pro. It's working great overall, but I'm annoyed by the need to move my right hand off of the keyboard in order to scroll.

Using PgUp/PgDown or Space/Shift-Space is insufficient for my needs, because I've become accustomed to analog control of scrolling, and the visual jump of scrolling a whole page -- not to mention losing sight of the last thing I was looking at, or even jumping past a bit of content (very common on websites with a fixed top navigation) -- is too disorienting.

To solve this, I would love to have a small analog pointing device, i.e. a scroll wheel or joystick or trackpoint or trackpad, that I could clip onto the side of my keyboard and manipulate with my index finger or thumb. It would have to have its own Bluetooth support or at least be easy to use with a USB-to-Bluetooth adapter.

I don't necessarily need the device to be ready-to-clip, as mounting could be jerry-rigged with binder clips or solved with a custom 3D printed part.

If there's anything that occurs to you that would fulfill my need but doesn't conform to the description above, I'd love to hear about it. (Perhaps I will have to take apart a cheap Bluetooth mouse and just keep the scroll wheel and PCB.)

Answer (score 2):

This was a hard one to find!

[This is my recommendation, the Griffin PowerMate Multi-Media Control Knob with Bluetooth Connectivity - Wirelessly control your Mac from Volume to Key Commands](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IRDRL4K)

It has software that will let you change what the knob does. So instead of Volumn Up/Down, you will make it scroll up/down.

The only reason I could see this not working is if the form factor is an issue, but Honestly I think this might be as close as were going to get lol.

EDIT*

Apparently, this company make a wide range of these types of products so if you don't like the aesthetic of this one, search by company name online and I'm sure you'll find something that meets your needs better.

Edit2*
[This "3d" mouse](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FJRRVII) might be an option as well, it doesn't meet all of your requirements but it looks pretty freaking cool

Edit 3*

Last one I swear, this is a wireless tiny trackpad that you might be able to keep on the desk where your thumb can get to it.... [Logitech Rechargeable Trackpad for Mac](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009JP461G).  I was trying to find a trackpad sticker... something that you could actually stick to the side of the keyboard frame and rub your finger on to scroll, but no luck on that front.

Alright that's all I have.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I'm looking for something smaller, but I appreciate the effort.